# How to initialise ViewModel properties in MVVM iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, mvvm

Based on some R&D, I am trying to implement MVVM for iOS. But, unable to initilize my View Model properties.

Here is my prob:

My View Controller:

In viewDidLoad:

`invViewModel  = [[MVVMHomeInvViewModel alloc] init];`

In “cellForRowAtIndexPath” , one of the custom cells,

```
if(indexPath.row==2){...
   UILabel *categoryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   categoryLabel.text= invViewModel.categoryLabel;
   …
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
.h:
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *categoryLabel;

.m:
@interface MVVMViewModel ()


// Private Access
@property (nonatomic, strong) MVVMModel *homeModel;
@end

@implementation MVVMHomeInvViewModel

- (instancetype)initWithHomeItems:(MVVMModel *)items{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;
    _categoryLabel = @"Categories";

    return self;
}

@end
```

Now, the label "Catgeories" is not displaying in my simulator.!!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm surprised at over 1k rep that you cannot format code properly in a question.  It will make it a lot easier to read if you do.

Comment: oops! Sorry about it. I just clicked Enter and submitted in hurry. I will definitely tc in future. When I relized, @nickfalk ahd alreday did my job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized my fault. My bad! I did not call the initilize method - initWithHomeItems in ViewModel, instead simply tried to access it with generic init method.

```
 homeInvCaptureViewModel = [[MVVMHomeInvViewModel alloc] initWithHomeItems];
```

This resolved the issue!